# CSS Order of Precendence

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="myLabel">Test1:</div>
    <div class="myControl"><input type="text" /></div>
    <div class="myLabel">Test2:</div>
    <div class="myControl"><input type="text" /></div>
    <div class="myLabel">Test3:</div>
    <div class="myControl"><input class="short" type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    width: 680px;
}
.myLabel {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
}
.myControl {
    display: inline-table;
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
}
.myControl > .short {
    width: 50px;
}
.myControl > input[type=text] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

What I am trying to do is make the last textbox take on the CSS style of `short`. Instead, it is being overwritten by the `input[type=text]` CSS rule. I know I can simply add an `!important` to my `.short` rule and make this work the way I want, but I am wondering why the `input[type=text]` rule seems to have more importance over the `.short` rule, since its first? And is there a better way to do this?

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hDA9/) of this behavior.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2hDA9/1/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21145861/1256925) will explain the order of precedence perfectly.

Comment: [The Shining](http://cssspecificity.com/), [Star wars](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) or [sea life](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all boils down to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You can fix this by appending the ID to that rule:

```
#myDiv .myControl > .short {
    width: 50px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2hDA9/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Rating rule:

```
A(0/1) -> style in-line
B(0/1) -> style associated with id
C(0/1) -> style associated with class
D(0/1) -> style associated with element
```

Score: `ABCD(in binary)`

Example:

```
#box h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Score: `A = 0; B = 1; C = 0; D = 1 => 0101 = 5 (win)`

```
h1 .title {
  color: red;
}
```

Score: `A = 0; B = 0; C = 1; D = 1 => 0011 = 3`

```
h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

Score: `A = 0; B = 0; C = 0; D = 1 => 0001 = 1`

In your case:

```
.myControl > .short {
   width: 50px;
}
```

Score: `A = 0; B = 0; C = 1; D = 0 => 0010 = 2`

```
.myControl > input[type=text] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Score: `A = 0; B = 0; C = 1; D = 1 => 0011 = 3(win)`

This rule is effective and easy to remember